# Real Bott periodicity in style of Harris’s proof of complex Bott periodicity

Tags: at.algebraic-topology

Bruno Harris has a beautiful short proof of complex Bott periodicity using the group completion theorem in his paper

B. Harris, Bott periodicity via simplicial spaces. J. Algebra 62 (1980), no. 2, 450--454.

Question: can these ideas be adapted to prove real Bott periodicity?

Comment: Maybe the paper of Gritschacher and Hausmann answers your question?